# Apache solr + Facet API, can I filter with node title?

Tags: 7, search

I am trying hard to find a text facet to filter the results by node title. Is it possible?

I tried the following method but facet is not appearing on the search page:

```
function biyixia_apachesolr_field_mappings_alter(&$mappings, $entity_type) {
  // Enable indexing for text fields
  $mappings['text'] = array(
    'indexing_callback' => 'apachesolr_fields_default_indexing_callback',
    'map callback' => '',
    'index_type' => 'string',
    'facets' => TRUE,
    'facet missing allowed' => TRUE,
    'dependency plugins' => array('bundle', 'role'),
    'hierarchy callback' => FALSE,
    'name_callback' => '',
    'facet mincount allowed' => FALSE,
    'multiple' => FALSE,
  );
}
```

Comment: Will node title will be repeated for several nodes ?

Comment: No, it will more likely be unique but I think it is irrelevant here

Comment: Managed to do it using my own module. Thanks for the comments